# Rotating image on button click

Tags: android

I had created a small app such that the image which is displaying should rotate when I click the button. I have written the following code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ImageActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }  
    public void Rotate()
    {

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView01);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bharath);
// Getting width & height of the given image.
        int w = bmp.getWidth();
        int h = bmp.getHeight();
// Setting pre rotate to 90
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.preRotate(90);
// Rotating Bitmap
        Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);
        img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
    }
```

Now when I execute the code and click the button to rotate the image, the application is forcing me to close it, mentioning there is an unexpected error. I could not trace and correct. Can any one please help me in this regard?

Comment: Please give people credit for their effort to help you and [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164138) on your previous questions. You haven't accepted a single answer!

Comment: Can you post some of the exception code from a logger such as logcat?

Comment: where is your button. From which activity you are calling the Rotate() method.

Comment: I have called my Rotate () function from main.xml file

Comment: 12-15 16:53:06.860: I/Process(538): Sending signal. PID: 538 SIG: 9



12-15 17:03:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)



12-15 17:03:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)


12-15 17:03:32.318: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)


is the Exception that I had got in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemme guess, you have `Button` in the layout `main.xml`, having this attribute `android:onClick="Rotate"`, in which the method defined in the `ImageActivity`, don't you?

If it is true, rewrite the definition of `Rotate()` like this: `public void Rotate(View v)`.
It should be working fine.

Additionally, you can just use:

```
img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBMP);
```

instead of wasting more memory on that `BitmapDrawable`